# Groovy: Why is Import required for classes in the same package?

Tags: groovy

A simple Groovy Class in a package *com.something*

```
package com.something

class A {
}
```

Another class in the same package

```
package com.something

class B {
    def variable=new A() //DOES NOT WORK TILL I EXPLICITLY say "import com.something.A"
}
```

Why Class B is not able to access class A, even though they both are in the same package?

Comment: How are you compiling? What's your file structure?

Comment: Both are groovy classes and both reside in the same project and in the same physical folder, right?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work" - does not compile? does not run? IDE is saying you need to import?
Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Both are in the same project ofcourse.
It does compile but fails while running

Comment: @tim_yates class B is used by a groovy script which is bind to IZPack, A Java based installer, lifecycle methods. 

The groovy script for IZPack lies in a different maven module, which has a dependency on the module which contains these two classes.

Comment: What IDE are you using? This should not be this way as long as both are in the same folder and package.

Comment: Intellij IDEA. But it is compiled externally using command line Maven. IDE is just for editing purpose

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using?  Could you share the relevant bits of your pom?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the question does not really have the needed information to answer it completely. But I can tell the following. If you make a directory ./com/something/ and out A.groovy and B.groovy in there and then compile them using the commandline `groovyc ./com/something/A.groovy ./com/something/B.groovy`, then this must work. So far the directory is not really important, but that changes if you change to `groovyc ./com/something/B.groovy`, because now groovyc has to "discover" A.groovy and requires the correct directory structure for this.

Now, how the ant, gradle and maven version of groovyc normally work is by supplying a complete list of sources. If this is not done, compilation may fail. But if the root directories for A and B are different and you do not give both to the compiler, then it will surely fail.

I cannot know if that is the reason, so I want this answer more understood as a pointer to what might be wrong. Hope this helps