# Groovy class can't locate superclass in the same package

Tags: java, groovy, groovyclassloader

I have a few [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) classes in the same package ( `com.company.config` ) in a multi-modular [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) project.

All used to inherit a `java` interface ( `MyInterface` ), but some refactoring was needed so I created a `groovy` abstract class which resides in the same package as the other scripts; it implements `MyInterface` and is inherited by the other scripts.

Ever since this change, I can't seem to execute the scripts from `java` code anymore.

In particular, `GroovyClassLoader::parseClass(File)` throws:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: 
startup failed:<|C:\my_workspace\a_project_name\modules\module-setup\src\com\company\config\MyScript1Impl.groovy: 
7: unable to resolve class com.company.config.AbstractGroovyClass
@ line 7, column 1.
import com.company.config.AbstractGroovyClass
^
```

At line 7, you can indeed find the import declaration

```
import com.company.config.AbstractGroovyClass
```

which I added (despite the class being in the same package) after the first time the same error was thrown and after I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888049/groovy-why-is-import-required-for-classes-in-the-same-package).

The `Exception` is triggered in the following line in the `java` code:

```
public Object getInstance(File sourceFile) {
    try {
      GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
      Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(sourceFile); // << Here
      Object inst = clazz.newInstance();
      // ....
    }
    // ...
}
```

whereas I call this function with the following parameters

```
getInstance(
    new File("./modules/module-setup/src/com/company/config/"
         className + ".groovy" // className = "MyScript1Impl" in this case
    )
);
```

As already stated, before the introduction of the abstract class, everything was working fine.

Why can't the `groovy` class find its superclass in the same package, even with the import declaration?

---

This is the stack-trace of the internal calls:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed ...
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:946)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:542)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:195)
```

*The rest stack trace is relative to the application calls so it's unhelpful.*

---

**Edit I**

I noticed indeed that the `GroovyClassLoader` does not know anything about other `groovy` classes and where they are located so I just added `"./modules/module-setup/src/com/company/config/"` in

```
GroovyClassLoader::addClassPath(String)
```

but I'm getting the same result as before.

The path is surely correct as the `File` instance is created with it and can be opened by the class loader.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it temporarily by loading the superclass via `GroovyClassLoader::parseClass` right before loading the actual inherited class.

```
final GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
// ...
// load superclass first
Class<?> abstractClass = gcl.parseClass(new File(classPath, "AbstractGroovyClass.groovy"));
// load the actual script
Class<?> clazz = gcl.parseClass(sourceFile);
```

It's definitely a bad answer as, if I had more `groovy` classes on which I depend on, I would have to manually parse them one by one. But it works...

Hoping someone can give a better answer.